# Execute an API call with authentication from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, api, authentication, response

I am not good at VBA programming (quite the basics), so I would like some of your input in the following matter as I couldn't find the correct answer for my concern. I would like to execute an API call with authentication using VBA. I have the below code but in Java (for test purposes), but my aim is to receive the responses in Excel. The idea is to login and fetch the records requested, and return it in form of XML or anything that would be readable ultimately in a wide Excel user form.

How to go about this? I do not need necessarily a-ready-code, any heads-up start would be appreciated.

```java
package tests;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import com.tgmtSystems.core.util.XML_Utils;

public class TestQueryService
{
    static String url = ".....";

    static String ACCOUNT = "......";
    static String USERNAME = ".....";
    static String PASSWORD = "***********";
    static String SERVICE = "queryservice.do";
    static String QUERY_SEARCH_INSTANCE_ID = "14289081";

    public static class ListResponse
    {
        String[ ] itemInstanceIds;
        String projectInstanceId;
        String templateInstanceId;
    }

    public static void main( String[ ] args )
    throws Exception
    {
        String credentials = TestQueryService.login( );
        ListResponse listResponse = listItems( credentials );
        getItem( credentials, listResponse, listResponse.itemInstanceIds[ 0 ] );
        
        //This will return the 10 first records identified by their Ids ( itemInstanceId )
        getItems( credentials, listResponse, "11324721,11324744,11324745,11324746,11324748,11324751,11324758,11324829,11324830,11324836" );
        
        //This will return All Ids, if there are more than 50, there will be an error, you can only fetch 50 at a time.
        //getItems( credentials, listResponse, StringUtils.join( listResponse.itemInstanceIds, "," ) );
    }

    public static String login( )
    throws Exception
    {
        String xmlRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><REQUEST><action>login</action><accountName>" + ACCOUNT + "</accountName><username>" + USERNAME + "</username><password>" + PASSWORD + "</password></REQUEST>";

        Document loginResponseDoc = sendRequest( xmlRequest );

        String credentials = XML_Utils.getNodeValue( "credentials", loginResponseDoc );
        return credentials;
    }

    public static ListResponse listItems( String credentials )
    throws Exception
    {
        String xmlRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><REQUEST><action>listItems</action><credentials>" + credentials + "</credentials><querySearchInstanceId>" + QUERY_SEARCH_INSTANCE_ID + "</querySearchInstanceId></REQUEST>";

        Document responseDoc = sendRequest( xmlRequest );

        ListResponse listResponse = new ListResponse( );

        listResponse.itemInstanceIds = StringUtils.split( XML_Utils.getNodeValue( "itemInstanceIds", responseDoc ), "," );
        listResponse.projectInstanceId = XML_Utils.getNodeValue( "projectInstanceId", responseDoc );
        listResponse.templateInstanceId = XML_Utils.getNodeValue( "templateInstanceId", responseDoc );

        return listResponse;
    }

    public static Document getItem( String credentials, ListResponse listResponse, String itemInstanceId )
    throws Exception
    {
        String xmlRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><REQUEST><action>getItem</action><credentials>" + credentials + "</credentials><templateInstanceId>" + listResponse.templateInstanceId + "</templateInstanceId><projectInstanceId>" + listResponse.projectInstanceId + "</projectInstanceId><itemInstanceId>" + itemInstanceId + "</itemInstanceId></REQUEST>";
        return sendRequest( xmlRequest );
    }
    
    public static Document getItems( String credentials, ListResponse listResponse, String itemInstancesId )
    throws Exception
    {
        String xmlRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><REQUEST><action>getItems</action><credentials>" + credentials + "</credentials><templateInstanceId>" + listResponse.templateInstanceId + "</templateInstanceId><projectInstanceId>" + listResponse.projectInstanceId + "</projectInstanceId><itemInstancesId>" + itemInstancesId + "</itemInstancesId></REQUEST>";
        return sendRequest( xmlRequest );
    }

    public static Document sendRequest( String xmlRequest )
    throws Exception
    {
        String type = "text/xml";

        System.out.println( "REQUEST\n" + xmlRequest );

        URL u = new URL( url + SERVICE );
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection( );
        conn.setDoOutput( true );
        conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", type );
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", String.valueOf( xmlRequest.length( ) ) );
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream( );
        os.write( xmlRequest.getBytes( ) );

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder( );
        try
        {
            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream( );
            if ( inputStream != null )
            {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( inputStream ) );
                char[ ] charBuffer = new char[ 128 ];
                int bytesRead = - 1;
                while ( ( bytesRead = bufferedReader.read( charBuffer ) ) > 0 )
                {
                    stringBuilder.append( charBuffer, 0, bytesRead );
                }
                bufferedReader.close( );
            }
            else
            {
                stringBuilder.append( "" );
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        String responseXML = stringBuilder.toString( );
        responseXML = responseXML.trim( );

        System.out.println( "RESPONSE\n" + responseXML );

        conn.disconnect( );

        return XML_Utils.getDocument( responseXML );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your attempt in VBA, and ask a specific question where you are stuck.